# Compile time memory allocation

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

This may seem a very basic question but it is related to how compiler works.
What is the sequence of memory allocation to local variables of a function.

Suppose I have a function

```
int a,b;
int c1;
int c,d;
int c2;
cout<<&a<<endl;
cout<<&b<<endl;
cout<<&c<<endl;
cout<<&d<<endl;
cout<<&c1<<endl;
cout<<&c2<<endl;
int f;
cout<<&f<<endl;
```

Here f gets the lowest memory address (relative wrt other variables) as if the initialisation stack was build like this:

```
a b c1 c d c2 f
```

and then memory was allocated

This might happen because there are various phases of compilation and this is one of them.

Which phase does this stack building up correspond to and in which phase is memory actually allocated?

Comment: @Nawaz: Strictly speaking not "implementation-defined" but "unspecified". "Implementation-defined" means that it must be defined and documented. Relative locations is not something that should be defined in any way - it may even be different during different runs (or even during different calls of the same function).

Comment: It like the [Heisenberg uncertainty principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) even looking at the variables changes their behavior. By taking their address you have changed how the compiler could layout the variables. If you had not taken their address they probably would not have even existed because the compiler optimized them out.

Answer (score 6):

There's no guarantee about what locations those variables will occupy - order of definition only influences order of constructors/destructors invokation.

Comment: I m not asking about what locations those will occupy but the relative memory addresses that will be assigned to these variables.

Comment: @Atishay: Memory addresses denote the location.

Comment: As @Nawaz pointed out, this is implementation defined ... the standard does not require any specific ordering, and so the ordering will depend mainly on the requirements of the hardware platform and how the compiler accommodates the needs of the underlying hardware.

Comment: Yes, but I am asking about their relative memory locations, I guess this would be guaranteed for a standard compiler, say gcc.

Comment: @Atishay: It is implemented as compiler designers see fit.

Comment: I doubt that this is *implementation-defined*. I'd rather say it's *implementation-specific*. The difference is that in the latter case the implementation does not have to document its choice.

Comment: @Roland Illig: That's called *unspecified*.

Comment: @Atishay: It's not. Even the same version of GCC can and will change the order depending on data type, optimization level and whatnot.

Answer (score 2):

There are no rules for how local variables are stored in memory, or **if** they are stored - they might live in a register for the entire function.

Some of them may even share the same memory location (provided they have separate lifetime and their addresses are not taken).

Comment: Does the same rules apply to the main function also

Comment: In this case, `main` is just a function. If you call other functions from `main`, the variables are likely to be stored in memory until you return again.

Answer (score 0):

The order in the code is not necessarily related to the order in memory at runtime.

To make the results a little more interesting, you can use differently-sized data types.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
  int i0;
  char c0, c1;
  int i1;
  short s0;

  cout << &i0 << endl;
  cout << (void *) &c0 << endl;
  cout << (void *) &c1 << endl;
  cout << &i1 << endl;
  cout << &s0 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Using g++ 3.4.4 on cygwin, Windows XP, 32bit, with `-Os` I got the following result:

```
0x22cce0
0x22ccdf
0x22ccde
0x22ccd8
0x22cce6
```

This suggests that the compiler groups the variables by their size, not by their declaration order. But in general you cannot rely on this. For example, changing the level of optimization to `-O0` did change the order in my case.

Comment: Reordering makes sense if you want to keep them properly aligned with a minimum number of pad bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It is compiler dependent. It depends on the type of parsing (top down or bottom up & left or right) done by the parser.

Comment: … and on many other things. So don't rely on anything here. If you really need a specific order, group all variables in a `struct`.